# How to select new generated node using Python in Maya?

Tags: python, maya

I am trying to create an automation to copy a shape by wrapping a polygon face to another polygon shape

```
# This script wrap a polygon face to the targeted terrain

import maya.cmds as cmds

# select terrain first, then the face
cmds.select( 'terrain', r = True )
cmds.select( 'face', add = True )

# wrapping a polygon face to the terrain
cmds.transferAttributes( transferPositions = 1 )

# NEW Node transferAttributes1 is created, change its attribute searchMethod to 1.
cmds.setAttr( 'transferAttributes1.searchMethod' , 1 )


# transferAttributes1 is generated after execution of 
# cmds.transferAttributes( transferPositions = 1 ). 
# The name might be different, such as transferAttributes2, transferAttributes3, etc.
# and cmds.setAttr( 'transferAttributes1.searchMethod' , 1 ) might give errors.
```

My question: Is there any way to select the new `transferAttributes` node and pass it to `cmds.setAttr()`?

PS: `transferAttributes*.searchMethod` might work, but it will select all `transferAttributes` nodes.

Answer (score 2):

`cmds.transferAttributes` will return the name of the node it creates:

```
cmds.select( 'terrain', r=True )
cmds.select( 'face', add=True )
new_node = cmds.transferAttributes( transferPositions=1 )[0]
cmds.setAttr( new_node +'.searchMethod' , 1 )
```

Comment: Thanks a million!

Comment: cmds.transferAttributes( transferPositions=1 ) returns a string list. new_node prints [u'transferAttributes1'], so cmds.setAttr( new_node[0] +'.searchMethod' , 1 )

Comment: Fixed, I did it from memory without checking.  Thansk

Answer (score 0):

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

cmds.select( 'terrain1', r=True )
cmds.select( 'face1', add=True )

cmds.transferAttributes( transferPositions=1 )

#select every transferAttributes Node and store them in a list. 
selection = cmds.ls('transferAttributes*');

#sort the list. 
selection.sort()

#select the last element from the list, thus the most recent node 
key = selection[-1]

cmds.setAttr( key+'.searchMethod' , 1 )
```